# Indy TIdFTP SSL unknown certificate

Tags: delphi, ssl, ftp, indy

I'm using Delphi 10.x and SSL FTP client code, and it works well on one FTP SSL server I'm using from OVH servers.
Nevertheless, it does not work on another one, and I do not see why.

I have a 10054 error.

I tested it on ftptest.net and this is OK, see below.

Here is the code related to TLS/SSL that I have added to the standard FTP client code

```pascal
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
FFtp.IOHandler              := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
FFTP.UseTLS                 := utUseExplicitTLS;
FFTP.DataPortProtection     := ftpdpsPrivate;
```

Here is the LOG file of ftptest.net

```
Status: Resolving address of s223.panelboxmanager.com

Status: Connecting to 2607:f748:1301:0:184:107:112:57

Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...

Reply: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

Reply: 220-You are user number 3 of 100 allowed.

Reply: 220-Local time is now 15:11. Server port: 21.

Reply: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login

Reply: 220 You will be disconnected after 2 minutes of inactivity.

Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of (Hidden IP)

Reply: 530 You aren't logged in

Command: AUTH TLS

Reply: 234 AUTH TLS OK.

Status: Performing TLS handshake...

Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...

Status: Received 2 certificates from server.

Status: cert[0]: subject='OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.panelboxmanager.com' issuer='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2'

Status: cert[1]: subject='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2' issuer='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA'

Command: USER XXXXX

Reply: 331 User XXXXX OK. Password required

Command: PASS *********

Reply: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /

Command: SYST

Reply: 215 UNIX Type: L8

Command: FEAT

Reply: 211-Extensions supported:

Reply: EPRT

Reply: IDLE

Reply: MDTM

Reply: SIZE

Reply: MFMT

Reply: REST STREAM

Reply: MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;

Reply: MLSD

Reply: AUTH TLS

Reply: PBSZ

Reply: PROT

Reply: UTF8

Reply: TVFS

Reply: ESTA

Reply: PASV

Reply: EPSV

Reply: SPSV

Reply: ESTP

Reply: 211 End.

Command: PBSZ 0

Reply: 200 PBSZ=0

Command: PROT P

Reply: 200 Data protection level set to "private"

Command: PWD

Reply: 257 "/" is your current location

Status: Current path is /

Command: TYPE I

Reply: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary

Command: EPSV

Reply: 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||33966|)

Command: MLSD

Status: Data connection established, performing TLS handshake...

Reply: 150 Accepted data connection

Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...

Status: Received 2 certificates from server.

Status: cert[0]: subject='OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.panelboxmanager.com' issuer='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2'

Status: cert[1]: subject='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2' issuer='C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA'

Status: TLS session of transfer connection has been resumed.

Listing: type=cdir;sizd=331776;modify=20201227201104;UNIX.mode=0711;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e40001; .

Listing: type=pdir;sizd=331776;modify=20201227201104;UNIX.mode=0711;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e40001; ..

Listing: type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20200914031725;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e40038; .autorespond

Listing: type=file;size=11333;modify=20200731001231;UNIX.mode=0600;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e4405e; .bash_history

Listing: type=file;size=33;modify=20091230222848;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e400a8; .bash_logout

Listing: type=file;size=296;modify=20190608053032;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e4013e; .bash_profile

Listing: type=file;size=205;modify=20190608052818;UNIX.mode=0644;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e40004; .bashrc

Listing: type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20190608053226;UNIX.mode=0775;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g5100940; .cache

Listing: type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20180727100540;UNIX.mode=0771;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e4003b; .cagefs

Listing: type=dir;sizd=4096;modify=20201215110057;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.uid=1432;UNIX.gid=1433;unique=ca06g4e4003d; .cl.selector

Reply: 226-Options: -a -l

Reply: 226 68 matches total

Status: Skipped display of 58 listing lines

Status: Success
```

Comment: Where's your code which shows what you already tried and where you failed? How does you current error handling look like?

Comment: Is you Delphi program a FTP server or a FTP client?

Comment: This is a client software.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by adding this, it solved the issue:

```pascal
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
```

Sometime this is very tricky .... also updated ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll to the latest versions here:

https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

I think this line can enable all SSL versions

```pascal
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Any comment welcome, if putting this line with all versions could be an issue.

Comment: [`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` enables only TLS 1.0 by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181), but many servers are phasing that out nowadays. Hence the need to enable TLS 1.1+ manually. Also, the `SSLOptions.Method` property is deprecated, use only the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property (but DO NOT enable `sslvSSLv2..sslvSSLv3`). And the [Fulgan mirror is deprecated](https://www.indyproject.org/2020/06/16/openssl-binaries-moved-to-github/), use https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries now.

Comment: "but DO NOT enable sslvSSLv2..sslvSSLv3"
Why not ? This is the only way I have to access my OVH FTP server AND s223.panelboxmanager.com FTP server... Otherwise what can I do with those SSLOptions.SSLVersions so that it works in a wide range of  FTP servers ?

Comment: SSL v2.0 and v3.0 are no longer secure, so nobody uses them anymore, and thus there is no good reason to ever enable them in modern code, except for accessing legacy systems. As for `sslvSSLv23`, that is a wildcard that Indy uses internally, there is no need to enable it manually (and in fact, Indy will just ignore it if any other version is enabled).

Comment: Remy, I know you are the Indy Guru, your name is all round the source code of this master piece.
Does it hurt if I put all of them in order to be compliant with as much as FTP server Imy software could connect to  ?  I'm just uploading image files that goes public to HTTP/s pages, so this is public data, so security is not my main concern here.

sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2